# Optimal way to implement 4*4 matrix and 3/4-element vector for 3D graphics in C#

Tags: c#, matrix, data-structures, 3d, linear-algebra

I'm about to implement offline raytracer for my educational purposes. Since I'm not planning to build a 3D graphics library, I do not need any generalizations for that structures like Generics, leet object-oriented design etc. The only goal is to achieve the fastest possible speed on my concrete environment. The structures I'm interested in are 4*4 matrix and 3/4 vector of doubles:

```
public struct Vec3_fields
{
    public double x, y, z;

    //constructors and methods
}
```

or

```
public unsafe struct Vec3_array
{
    public fixed double v[3];

    public Vec3_array(double p0, double p1, double p2)
    {
        fixed (Vec3_array* p = &this)
        {
            p->v[0] = p0;
            p->v[1] = p1;
            p->v[2] = p2;
        }
    }
}
```

Same goes for Vec4.
Now there are options for matrix. This is how it's [done in GLM](https://github.com/g-truc/glm/blob/bcd07b50f30142be85d7c1664993c460f0e9237f/glm/detail/type_mat4x4.hpp)

```
public struct Mat4_array_of_Vec4
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
    private readonly Vec4[] value;

    public Mat4_array_of_Vec4(
        double p00, double p01, double p02, double p03,
        double p10, double p11, double p12, double p13,
        double p20, double p21, double p22, double p23,
        double p30, double p31, double p32, double p33)
    {
        value = new[]
        {
            new Vec4(p00, p01, p02, p03),
            new Vec4(p10, p11, p12, p13),
            new Vec4(p20, p21, p22, p23),
            new Vec4(p30, p31, p32, p33)
        };
    }
}
```

Another option is to code all 16 fields explicitly like in Vec3_fields:

```
public double x0, y0, z0, w0, x1 ... w3;
```

And the last obvious way to have an array of length 16 [as in MathDotNet](https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-numerics/blob/master/src/Numerics/LinearAlgebra/Storage/DenseColumnMajorMatrixStorage.cs):

```
public fixed double v[16];
```

I'm interested in performance aspects of each representation like spatial locality and .net specific issues.

Comment: Why do you want it to be unmanaged?

Comment: I did it to get fixed size buffer.